# How to generate path of a directory in python

Tags: python, path, operating-system, listdir

I have a file `abc.py` under the workspace dir.

I am using `os.listdir('/home/workspace/tests')` in `abc.py` to list all the files (`test1.py`, `test2.py`...)

I want to generate the path  `'/home/workspace/tests'` or even `'/home/workspace'` instead of hardcoding it.

I tried `os.getcwd()` and `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(____file____))` but this instead generates the path where the test script is being run.

How to go about it?

Comment: Generate it from what information? How is `/home/workspace/tests` related to the working directory, the location of the script/module, or some other data you have available?

Comment: The only paths available to the script are the current working directory and the location the file is placed. How is the Python script to 'know' about `/home/workspace` otherwise? What is that path based on?

Comment: If you want to list all the files in a directory then visit this duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python

Comment: (Also, naming your script `abc.py` is a mildly bad idea; `abc` is a stdlib module, although granted one that you're unlikely to use very often.)

Comment: If `/home/workspace` is a home directory of a user, and you want to base your paths on that, have a look at [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser).

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can refer to a specific folder from which you don't relate in any way and you don't want to hardcode it, is to pass it as a parameter to the script ([search for: command line argument](http://bit.ly/1beYNfJ))

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about how to get the relative path instead of absolute one.

Absolute path is the one like: "/home/workspace"

Relative looks like the following "./../workspace"

You should construct the relative path from the dir where your script is (/home/workspace/tests) to the dir that you want to acces (/home/workspace) that means, in this case, to go one step up in the directory tree.

You can get this by executing:
os.path.dirname(os.path.join("..", os.path.abspath(**__file__**)))

The same result may be achieved if you go two steps up and one step down to workspace dir:
os.path.dirname(os.path.join("..", "..", "workspace", os.path.abspath(**__file__**)))

In this manner you actually can access any directory without knowing it's absolute path, but only knowing where it resides relatively to your executed file.